# How can print a php array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array `$results` and I need to use it inside my javascript part of the code. I tried json_encode() but it did not work..

Here is the code

```
<?php
    //...
    include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Controllers/ReportController.php');
    $vaccRep= ReportController::getVacRep();

    include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Controllers/VaccineController.php');
    $names=VaccineController::getVCName();
?>

<canvas id="bar" height="195" width="250" style="width: 250px; height: 195px;"></canvas>
<script>
    //THIS IS THE PART THAT WILL BE THE OTPUT OF THE QUERY

    var barChartData = {
        labels: <?php$obj=json_encode($names); var_dump($obj);?>,
        datasets: [{
            highlightFill: "#45668e",
            highlightStroke: "#45668e",
            fillColor : "#1ABC9C",
            strokeColor : "#1ABC9C",
            data: <?php $obj=json_encode($vaccRep); var_dump($obj);?>
        }]
    };


    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
    <?php $obj=json_encode($vaccRep); var_dump($obj);?>
</script>
```

Comment: Share the code you've tried.

Comment: you can json_encode your array in php and use it in javascript.

Comment: Your problem solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply echo the php array in js with `json_encode()`, like this :

```
$phpArray = array('name'=>'mani','email'=>'test@gmail.com','mobile'=>'123467890');
```

PHP array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [name] => mani
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [mobile] => 123467890
)

<script>
var jsArray = [];
var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray);?>;
console.log(jsArray);
</script>
```

You will get this in your console

```
 Object { name="mani",  email="test@gmail.com",  mobile="123467890"}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<?php
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var $results = JSON.parse('" . json_encode($results) . "');";
    echo "<script>";
?>
```

and then use $results in your javascript code anywhere but make sure this script block is loaded before you are using it.

Comment: You should not need the `JSON.parse()` as `json_encode()` will produce valid javascript object

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to print a php array in javascript

```
<?php
  $abc=["a","b","c"];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var abc = "<?php echo (implode(',',$abc));?>";
  var abcArr = abc.split(",");
  console.log(abcArr);
</script>
```

Comment: What if there are strings that contain comma in this array? eg. `["a,", "b", "c"]`. Additional empty string will be in that array, which is incorrect.

Comment: @YuriyYakym, whats your suggestion to prevent this. I just provided the way.

Comment: Your solution could be used only in case if we are sure that we use separator which is not a part of any array elements.

Comment: Yes totally agreed

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code:

```
<?php
    $array = ["a", 1, 2, "b,"];
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var data = ".json_encode($array).';';
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

The output of this code will be:
`<script>var data = ["a",1,2,"b,"];</script>`, what will create correct javascript array.